# BarCode reader component for Silverlight/.net, resources, recommendations, animal crossing? oh my

Tags: c#, silverlight, components, barcode, silverlight-oob

I'm looking for a barcode reader component.  Hoping to use it in a Silverlight Out of browser Application.  Eventually be ported for usage in windows 8. Hoping to supliment physical bar code readers.  Possibly reading other types the physical device may not be able to decode.

http://blog.lemqi.com/?cat=3 a posting from 2008 has a round up comparing different components.  A few look promising but it's a bit dated.

General recommendations, or general products to stay away from would be greatly appreciated.  Open source projects are welcome, I briefly looked at a Silverlight port of Zebra Crossing(zxing) but the documentation looked scarce.

Looking for something that will work world wide, and detects the barcode types.

Comment: There are a number of barcode readers that can install themselves as a HID keyboard device. Would that work for you?

Comment: We use physical bar code readers already.  This is for circumstances where the physical device is unavailable.

Comment: How do you want to get the barcode image without a device?

Comment: Webcam is used to scan a barcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

Nice little added wrapper for Zebra Crossing for Silverlight.  Had some other features I was considering using.

If anyone is interested, grab the source code, there are examples. Basic run down incase anyone is interested.

**Add Dependencies**

App.xaml.cs

```
Decoders.AddDecoder<PngDecoder>(); //or whatever format your barcode is in.
```

**Load Image**

```
FileInfo fileInfo = path;
var extendedImage = new ExtendedImage();
extendedImage.SetSource(fileInfo.OpenRead());
Image.Source=extendedImage;  //Image is of type AnimatedImage and found in the xaml.
```

**Scan Image**

```
IBarcodeReader barcodeReader = new ZxingBarcodeReader(true, BinarizerMode.Hybrid)
BarcodeResult result = barcodeReader.ReadBarcode(Image.Source);

// Set some values in the xaml for results

Barcode.Text = result.Text
BarcodeFormat.Text = result.Format.ToString();
```

This is more or less the example.  I just trimmed it down so people could understand it at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, the [ClearImage Barcode Recognition SDK](http://www.inliteresearch.com/barcode-recognition/) from Inlite Research should work well for you. It's designed for Windows with COM and .Net APIs so should have no issues with Silverlight or Windows 8.

It handles all popular 1D and 2D barcodes types and reliably handles all types of damaged barcodes (which happen more often than you may think).

*Note: I have done some work for Inlite*

Comment: The engine looks okay, but it has a pretty high failure rate when I tossed the sample images from the blog I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Siverlight provides access to the Webcam, but I haven't done that yet. I would be a little wary, as you probably are, of a vendor-based review/comparison that you linked to. 
I have heard good things about http://www.atalasoft.com/ but I haven't used it.
http://accusoft.com/ worked well in Silverlight for me, but I didn't use the AccuSoft barcode module. 
If the user will provide 90 degree-ish alignment with the camera, you'll probably be good with any open source bar code library or writing your own.

Comment: Yah I don't think the Atalasoft Barcode side of things is compatible with a Silverlight projects, it literally removed itself.   I started looking at Accusoft, going to dive more into it today.  Just need to find some basic documentation.  I have no idea why everything has to be so complicated in terms of documentation.  It just seems like open source projects on git hub typically have better documentation than vendors.  I would be happy with just some unit tests.